# xslt case change transformation is removing the <br/ > tag from xml

Tags: xslt

I am doing a upper case to first character content in the xml data using the delimiters (space and hyphen) and am able to get the output correctly however this template is removing the break line 
 tag in  the table td area of xml. The output should be an xml.

```
eg:<text>
                    <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>test<br />testing<br />tested</td>
                                </tr>
```

I see the code transforming as continous line without break tag in the output as below:I need to see the same br tag in xml output as in input xml however by capitalizing first letter of the word.

```
<text>
                    <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Testtestingtested</td>
                                </tr>
```

I am expecting to preserve and display the same break line tag to be in output xml even after the xslt tranformation so that the output will look correct instead of continous line

I am using the below xslt transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
xmlns:n1="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:n2="urn:hl7-org:sdtc">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match='n1:ClinicalDocument/n1:component/n1:structuredBody/n1:component/n1:section/n1:text/n1:table/n1:tbody/n1:tr'>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select='n1:td'/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="n1:td">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="./@ID">
          <xsl:attribute name="ID" xml:space="default">
            <xsl:value-of select="./@ID"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>             
          <xsl:call-template name="capitalize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="string(.)"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:text>&#xd;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="capitalize">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select = "' '"/>      
    ​
    <xsl:variable name="upper-case" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="lower-case" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>

    <xsl:variable name="word" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
    <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="$delimiter=' '">
            <!-- tokenize word by 2nd delimiter -->
            <xsl:call-template name="capitalize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$word"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="'-'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- capitalize word -->
          <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($word, 1, 1), $lower-case, $upper-case) " />
          <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($word, 2), $upper-case, $lower-case)" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
      <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
      <!-- recursive call -->
      <xsl:call-template name="capitalize">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"  />
      </xsl:call-template>      
    </xsl:if>   
  </xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can anyone check and answer?

Comment: try the `<br><xsl:value-of select="//br"/></br>` on your template or create a new template   `<xsl:template match="br"><br/></xsl:template>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE: Both XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 solutions**

All solutions preserve your line breaks and also work if you have inline markup of the text content.

First I make the lc and uc parameters global for more minified templates:

```
<xsl:param name="lc" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿžšœ'"/>
<xsl:param name="uc" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞŸŽŠŒ'"/>
```

**XSLT 1.0 or 2.0**: You need to rewrite your first template to this regardless of the following XSLT solutions:

```
<xsl:template match="n1:td">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:if test="./@ID">
         <xsl:attribute name="ID" xml:space="default">
            <xsl:value-of select="./@ID"/>
         </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>             
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
   </xsl:copy>
   <xsl:text>&#xd;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

With XSLT 1.0 you need to combine a match template with a name template.

Match template: n1:td//text()

With this match template it becomes precisely what you request, make initial letter uppercase, and make letters following space and - uppercase:

```
<xsl:template match="n1:td//text()" >
    <xsl:param name="text" select="." />
    <xsl:param name="currentTextBlock" select="ancestor::n1:td[1]" />
    <xsl:param name="isFirstTextNode">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="preceding::text()[ancestor::n1:td[generate-id(.) = generate-id($currentTextBlock)]]">false</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>true</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$isFirstTextNode = 'true'">
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($text, 1, 1), $lc, $uc)" />
            <xsl:call-template name="capitalize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text" />
                <xsl:with-param name="remainingText" select="substring($text,2)" />
                <xsl:with-param name="index" select="2" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="capitalize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text" />
                <xsl:with-param name="remainingText" select="$text" />
                <xsl:with-param name="index" select="1" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

If you *also* want initial letter for each text node to be uppercase without adding space or hyphen, you can use this:

```
<xsl:template match="n1:td//text()" >
    <xsl:param name="text" select="." />
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($text, 1, 1), $lc, $uc)" />
    <xsl:call-template name="capitalize">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text" />
        <xsl:with-param name="remainingText" select="substring($text,2)" />
        <xsl:with-param name="index" select="2" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

Name template: capitalize

This name template is can be used "as is" with both of the above match templates.

```
<xsl:template name="capitalize">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="''" />
    <xsl:param name="remainingText" select="''" />
    <xsl:param name="index" select="1" />
    <xsl:if test="$remainingText != ''">
        <xsl:variable name="currentChar" select="substring($remainingText, 1, 1)" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$index = 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="translate($currentChar, $uc, $lc)" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:variable name="previousChar" select="substring($text, $index - 1, 1)" />
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$previousChar = ' ' or $previousChar = '-'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="translate($currentChar, $lc, $uc)" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="translate($currentChar, $uc, $lc)" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:call-template name="capitalize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text" />
            <xsl:with-param name="remainingText" select="substring($remainingText, 2)" />
            <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index + 1" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

**XSLT 2.0** (same as before):

This solution does precisely what you request, make initial letter uppercase, and make letters following space and - uppercase:

```
<xsl:template match="n1:td//text()" >
  <xsl:param name="text" select="." />
  <xsl:param name="currentTextBlock" select="ancestor::n1:td[1]" />
  <xsl:param name="isFirstTextNode">
     <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="preceding::text()[ancestor::n1:td[generate-id(.) = generate-id($currentTextBlock)]]">false</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>true</xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:param>
  <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(replace(replace($text,'(.)','$1\\n'),'\\n$',''),'\\n')">
     <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
     <xsl:variable name="char" select="." />
     <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$isFirstTextNode = 'true' and $pos = 1">
           <xsl:value-of select="translate($char, $lc, $uc) " />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="substring($text, $pos - 1, 1) = ' ' or substring($text, $pos - 1, 1) = '-'">
           <xsl:value-of select="translate($char, $lc, $uc) " />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:value-of select="translate($char, $uc, $lc)" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

If you *also* want initial letter for each text node to be uppercase without adding space or hyphen, you can use this:

```
<xsl:template match="n1:td//text()" >
  <xsl:param name="text" select="." />
  <xsl:param name="currentTextBlock" select="ancestor::n1:td[1]" />
  <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(replace(replace($text,'(.)','$1\\n'),'\\n$',''),'\\n')">
     <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
     <xsl:variable name="char" select="." />
     <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$pos = 1">
           <xsl:value-of select="translate($char, $lc, $uc) " />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="substring($text, $pos - 1, 1) = ' ' or substring($text, $pos - 1, 1) = '-'">
           <xsl:value-of select="translate($char, $lc, $uc) " />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:value-of select="translate($char, $uc, $lc)" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I need to capitalize the words after delimiters (space and hyphen) as well and this will work for capitalizing first letter only in td..the code in capitalize will actually do a upper case for every first letter after space and after hypen eg: desired output ``` <td>Jtest-Radiology West <br /> Test</td>```

Comment: I misunderstood your request, see the updated answer.

Comment: Daniel,thank you for the code however I am using xslt 1.0 and getting an error when using the function tokenize(replace(replace($text,'(.)','$1\\n'),'\\n$',''),'\\n')"> Can you please give an substitute for this piece of code in xslt 1.0.Thank you.

Comment: See updated answer. I have added XSLT 1.0 solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel..this is the exact code which I wanted.Thank you again.

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your call on `string(.)`, which takes the string value of the element: this strips out all markup.

You should be doing a recursive descent using `xsl:apply-templates` at each level to apply template rules to child nodes, all the way down to the leaf text nodes, and then your template rule for text nodes should be doing the case conversion.

Except that your `capitalize` logic seems to be trying to do something smart (I'm not sure what) which means it might need to look at something larger than a single text node. You might need a different rule for the first text node and for subsequent text nodes: it's hard to be sure without seeing a spec.

Another approach to this kind of problem is to do multiple passes: the first pass replaces the `<br/>` elements with some textual marker, e.g. "§br§", in the next pass you process the text as a string, and then finally you convert the markers back to element nodes.

With XSLT 3.0 you could do the first pass using `fn:serialize()` and the final pass using `fn:parse-xml-fragment()`; the "textual marker" would then be the actual lexical markup `"<br/>"` as a string of five characters. (But take care not to capitalise it!)